# Cleanest way to theme page contained in a node.js module?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js

I'm using scribe.js to log in my node.js application. This module provide a 'web panel' to consult log in a web page that has its css, its html structure and so on. The code of this webpage is contained in a directory of scribe.js module. I can, of course, modify it directly to style the page, but it is not a 'clean' way for if I want to redistribute my application that has scribe.js in its dependecies, people downloading my app would install scribe.js without any of my customization.

So, i believe the real question is: I can add css to a page created by another module?

The 'web panel' can be included calling this line of code

```
 app.use('/logs', scribe.webPanel());
```